# Firestore Rules Occasional Permission Denied

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I'm making a journaling app with Flutter that has journals and journal entries.

Here are my firestore rules that have been working for the most part:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /journals/{journal} {
      allow read, update, delete: if resource.data.users.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /journalEntries/{journalEntry} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/journals/$(resource.data.journal)).data.users.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I run into happens about half the time when adding journals:

```
W/Firestore(31194): (24.0.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(journalEntries where journal == GivKPhcnen8OmCDOcXs3 order by -dateCreated, -__name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter (31194): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

To clarify, I add a journal document, and then immediately query all the journal entries for that journal, which there are none initially.

Everything works fine if I remove the "get(/databases/$(database)/documents/journals/$(resource.data.journal)).data.users.hasAny([request.auth.uid])" part in the rules but I need that for security. The only thing I can think of is that there is some race condition happening where firestore rules don't think the journal document has been created yet when I start querying the journal entries for the new journal.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas of what is going on?

Writing to the Firestore database is asynchronous. What's probably going on is that you try to read before the write operation is complete and therefore the security rule does not find the newly created `journal` document.

We don't see your code, but do you wait that the asynchronous write operation is complete before fetching the `journalEntries` collection?

---

In addition, remember that [Firestore security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). It means that your query to the `journalEntries` collection must filter the documents that have the user uid in the `users` array.

Comment: That's what I have been looking at and I don't see any issues there. I'll keep looking

Comment: Can you share your Flutter code? Analysing Security rules without seeing the corresponding queries is very difficult, if not meaningless.

Comment: So after some more refactoring, it looks like that was the issue. I moved the code that starts my snapshot listner into the whenComplete callback for the document set(). The only problem left is that this only seems to work when online.

Comment: any idea how to support this while offline?

Comment: Nope. If your security rule is dependent on the creation of a new document in Firestore, I don't see how this could be possible offline. Other approaches could be to use some Custom Claims or to write to a staging Firestore collection, but do need to be analyzed in detail.

Comment: PS: Custom Claims would probably not be a viable solution, since the token needs to be refreshed to propagate a new claim.

Comment: That's weird. I can immediately get the new document from the snapshot listener when offline but security rules block it when I'm online. Hmmm

Comment: "I can immediately get the new document from the snapshot listener when offline" => This is because the new document is saved in the local cache (more info [here in the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) and  you will also find several answers on that on SO). When your device get online there is probably a lag before the newly created doc is persisted in Firestore, hence the security rule problem. This is just an assumption and would need to be confirmed with a dedicated test/POC.